# How to pass form data between template files in WP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to identify which search form is used by the user in WP and depending on the answer, output a specific template.

I have a general idea of how to accomplish it, but WP does not hand form information over to the search.php template. For example a input value.

> How could one provide search.php with submitted form data?

This is what I have so far;

**located in archive.php**

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="formName" value="globalSearch"/>
</form
```

**Located in search.php**

```
<?php $formIdentifier = $_GET['formName']; ?>
<?php if ( strcmp( $formIdentifier, 'globalSearch' ) ) { ?>
    // Show foo
<?php } else { ?>
    // Show bar
<?php } ?>
```

And this is the response from the browser:

> **Notice:** Undefined index: formName in -
>
> */wp-content/themes/understrap-child/search.php*

---

**EDIT:** 26 Jun 2019 @ 15:38

After some testing it turned out WP was doing some fancy stuff with my urls, resulting in cleaner urls such as; `www.example.com/posts/hello-world` You can't access the `$GET` variable without it displaying in the browser (At least to my knowledge.)

Disabling this feature means my urls now read; `www.example.com/s=testing&formName=catalogueSearch&submit=` and now the `search.php` argument I have built works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet.

```
if(isset($_GET['formName'])) {
    $type = $_GET['formName'];
    if($type == 'globalSearch') {
        load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/normal-search.php');
    } elseif($type == 'books') {
        load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/global-search.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: I did think about it, but seeing as I'm dealing with two different post types too I wanted to avoid the headache of over complicating things. :)

Comment: @Beaniie Can you try the updated answer? try it in 'search.php'

Comment: I'll give it a go. :)